# Sprites not rendering in build. Unity [Fixed]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cinemachine

im trying to put my game in a build, however, some sprites arnt rendering, mostly things that dont collide, im the scene and game view they are visible, but in the build they arnt, here are screenshots of the views and build settings

Edit: im also using cinemachine

Edit 2: it seems that the only things that dont show are things with sprite shape controllers and sprite shape renderers.

Build Settings
[image: Build Settings]

Game View in unity editor
[image: Game View in unity editor]

Scene view
[image: Scene View]

Build view
[image: View in build]

files of build i think
[image: files]

I cant think of what to try, since it shouldn't change from editor to build.

my problem was that the profile on the sprite shape renderer didnt have a profile set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the log of the build. Go to: `C:\Users\<YourUser>\AppData\LocalLow\<Company-Name-Set-In-Unity>\<Project-Name-Set-In Unity>`. There should be a file called `output_log.txt`.

Open that file to see if your build has potential issues to solve. E.g. you are using the wrong path only valid for the editor but not a build (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html)

Comment: ive gone to that, but i cant see output_log.txt, only the files Player.log and Player-prev.log

Comment: i might have found it, im testing it now

Comment: @UltraAce I am assuming it's fixed?